# Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have an activity and a fragment within that activity. The fragment is loaded within the activity `onCreate()`.

```
if (!supportFragmentManager.isDestroyed) {
    val fragmentTransaction = this.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerLayout, fragment).commit()
}
```

Inside the fragment, I am performing an API call and when the result is received, the activity gets the callback and the result is passed to the fragment from the activity.

The issue is when I load this activity and when the API is still on call if I press the device recents button then the app crashes showing the below exception.

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
```

I understand that the problem is the fragment tries to commit after `onSaveInstanceState` is called. But how is that happening I am not clear. I went through the [article](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html) too. It says three points as solution.

1. To commit the fragment within onCreate() which I am already doing.
2. Not to commit in onPostExecute() which is not applicable to me.
3. Use commitAllowingStateLoss() only as a last resort.

Should I need to change `commit()` to `commitAllowingStateLoss()`? As I went through the docs, I don't feel that safe too. Could someone suggest to me the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't use commitAllowingStateLoss(). I put the code as:

```
var isAnException: Boolean = false

try {
    if (!supportFragmentManager.isDestroyed) {
        val fragmentTransaction = this.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerLayout, fragment).commit()
    }
} catch (exception: IllegalStateException) {
   isAnException = true
}
```

and in onResume() of my activity, I added the below code to make the fragment work when taken from the recents.

```
override fun onResume() {
   if (isAnException) {
      isAnException = false
      //fragment load and set the views
   }
   super.onResume()
}
```